# Segregation Data in SQL for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

is there a sql construct for postgres to handle automatic data segregation?
I have to extract, for every single user, the data associated to it without using conditions in the "where" clause. Example an italian user can to display only data for italian web site, a russian user can to display only data for russian web site. Furthermore an super user can to display datas for italian and russian web site. Can I to use a one user, example 'postgres', for all connections came from my application server, used by different users, on postgres if exists this construct?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You need a way to find out in SQL what your permissions are. Then you can use [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html).

Comment: I had already seen the RLS but  how do I solve the problem of connections with a single postgres user for everyone?For this i don't find any answer

Comment: Create views. Grant access to those instead of to the base tables.

Comment: You want to filter the rows, but without using the feature that SQL provides for filtering? That doesn't make any sense.